# mqtt server in docker - a way to run the <mosquitto_passwd -U> from DockerCompose.yaml

Tags: docker, mqtt

finally got mqtt running in Docker, but I want to use uid/pwd. Got all of it working, by:

1. 1st using  a mosquitto.conf file that does not ask for the passwd file,
2. firing up the mqtt service via a DockerCompose.yaml from the mqtt image 3. have created,
3. then logging into the service with `docker exec -it containerid sh`,
4. I then, in the service, run the command `mosquitto_passwd -U passwdfile` to encrypt the open passwords I have in the file;
5. Then I stop the stack of the docker service, change the mosquitto.conf for the location of the passwordfile, stsrtup the stack and the service again, then it works.

If I do not do it like this, the mqtt container exits, and says the passwd file is not encrypted correctly.

So, is their a way to maybe run the encrypt command in the docker container before the mqtt server expects it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use an `ENTRYPOINT` script to run `mosquitto_passwd` before starting the `mosquitto` service.  Use a Dockerfile like this:

```
FROM eclipse-mosquitto

COPY entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "/entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["/usr/sbin/mosquitto","-c","/mosquitto/config/mosquitto.conf"]
```

And an `entrypoint.sh` script that looks like:

```
#!/bin/sh

PASSWDFILE=/etc/mosquitto/passwd

if [ -f $PASSWDFILE ]; then
    echo "converting password file"
    mosquitto_passwd -U $PASSWDFILE
fi

exec "$@"
```

When you start a container from this image, it will run `mosquitto_passwd` before starting the `mosquitto` service.

There are some problems with this example: in particular, since `mosquitto_passwd` modifies the file in place, you would need to ensure you don't attempt to convert a file that has already been converted.

Hopefully this gives you some ideas on how to build a more complete solution.

Comment: Thank you very much for a very complete answer. I never really understoor how the entrypoint is to be used.

Answer (score 6):

Another alternative is to run `mosquito_passwd` inside the container, i.e. on the container shell. Here is what worked for me (note that I have the config directory persisted outside the container):

0. Create your `mosquitto_passwords` file in the config directory
1. Enter the container

```
$ docker exec -it mosquitto sh
```

(Where `mosquitto` is the name of the mosquitto container)

2. Navigate to your password file

```
/ $ cd mosquitto/
/mosquitto $ ls
config  data    log
/mosquitto $ cd config/
/mosquitto/config $ ls
mosquitto.conf       mosquitto_passwords
```

3. Run mosquitto_passwd to hash your password file

```
/mosquitto/config $ mosquitto_passwd -U mosquitto_passwords
```

If you get an error like

```
Error: Unable to open password file /mosquitto/config/mosquitto_passwords. Permission denied.
```

you need to make sure that your password file and the config directory is accessible to the container-user. To find out which user that is  do

```
/mosquitto/config $ whoami
whoami: unknown uid 1000
```

So in this case you can do

```
$ sudo chown 1000 config
$ sudo chown 1000 config/mosquitto_passwords
```

After that,

```
/mosquitto/config $ mosquitto_passwd -U mosquitto_passwords
```

should work fine and you're done.

4. Exit the container

```
/mosquitto/config $ exit
```

Don't forget to point your `mosquitto.conf` at your new password file.

Answer (score 3):

An alternative is use the eclipse-mosquitto docker container directly to create the file and then copy the file created. This is useful, especially if you just want to create password file for one or two users

Start the docker container, but overriding the entry point.

```
docker run -it --entrypoint sh -v $(pwd):/pwd eclipse-mosquitto
```

Here I'm also using the volume mount options, to mount my current directory into the container at `/path`.

This will start a shell.

```
cd /path   # if you've opted to do this
mosquitto_passwd -b -c passwd FreddaBlogs ABetterPassw0rdGoesHere
cat passwd
# cut'n'paste the output
```

`ctrl-d` to exit the shell - and the file will have been created in the local directory.  As this was created by the root user in the docker containers, you might need to change the owner permissions etc.